# iPhone app codeSigning only fails for "device + release"

Tags: iphone, release, codesign

I can compile and install (on the iphone) several of the apps I've written.

I have 1 generic "*" certificate for developing any app.  (It expires in 6 days)

I have individual "com.site.appName" for distributing each app.

But there's this 1 app, that just started giving:

```
warning: Application failed codesign verification.   
The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple  
submission certificate. (-19011)
```

I only get the above error when I try using "device + release" setting.

It still can be installed on the phone... and seems to run fine.
(Isn't that impossible if isn't not code-signed?)

When I try "device + debug" or "device + distribute", there's no signing error at all.
(So I know I have SOMETHING set correctly.)

I assume all this means I have something set wrong in my "project info + device + release" values.  (But where????)

Or I should I be checking my "target info + device + release" values instead?

Answer (score 0):

This might work, might not, but it fixes a lot of these situations:

1. Download iPhone Configuration Utility
2. Kill Xcode
3. Delete all profiles using iPCU
4. Plug in your phone, find the list of profiles, and select "remove" for ALL of them
5. Manually drag/drop each profile into iPCU, from the Finder
6. Restart XCode

...because XCode's internal code for selecting the right certificates to use for code-signing is buggy. No particular reason for this, just Apple didn't write it very well. It's getting better, but even in latest Xcode it still sometimes goes wrong.

NEVER use xcode to install a provisioning profile - no matter what Apple says, the Xcode install-handling code is still buggy, whereas strangely the iPCU code is not.

Also, your phone will sometimes have multiple versions of the same profile (which ought to be impossible, but it's not) ... iPCU lets you fix that

Answer (score 0):

If it can be installed into iPhone, it wasn't signed with distribution certificate, but with development one. Check project->settings, target->settings if correct identity (iPhone Distribution) is selected for Release-Device configuration.